# What does 'One' mean in the name of various fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am not much of a typography expert. Unfortunately the word 'one' is very common so Google/Bing return no reasonable results.

Common examples include:

[Francois One](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Francois+One), [Fjalla One](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Fjalla+One), [Days One](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Days+One), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can assume 2 variants:

1. This is the version 1 of the font.
2. The [PostScript type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_1) of the font is 1:

Type 1 (also known as PostScript, PostScript Type 1, PS1, T1 or Adobe Type 1) is the font format for single-byte digital fonts for use with Adobe Type Manager software and with PostScript printers. It can support font hinting.
It was originally a proprietary specification, but Adobe released the specification to third-party font manufacturers provided that all Type 1 fonts adhere to it.

- I see I have no choice, so I give the right answer:
  For no reason. They just liked the word "ONE".

Comment: I don't think either of those are the case here. Versioning is typically written with numerals. And these are OTF (Or TTF) fonts.

Comment: @DA01 the third variant I wanted to write was: NO ANY REASON AT ALL. That's the right answer actually. Updated ;)

Comment: Yes, that's the likely answer. I'm not aware of any particular type naming convention, but now that I think about it, the sample typefaces only have one weight and style available. Perhaps that's the significance of the 'One'.

Comment: @DA01 :) probably, but who knows that it will be only one weight and style for a font? I saw font ONE with different variations of style in the same family

Comment: I thought 'One' would indicate some characteristic feature of the font, since many of 'One' fonts I have seen so far have 'modern' appearance and look good as headlines, IMHO. I will leave this question unanswered for a certain time, hoping that other people will also feel invited to share their knowledge on this.